# Django UpdateView wont delete tha old entry if primary key is edited

Tags: python, django, model

So lets say we have this model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    am = models.SmallIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True) # XXX: max_value = 10000
    date_enrolled = models.DateField('Date Enrolled')
    semester = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    undergraduate = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

An update view like this:

```
class StudentUpdateView(SqlPresenterMixin, StudentMixin, UpdateView):   
    model = Student
    form_class = StudentForm
    template_name = "profapp/student_form.html"
    slug_field = "am"
```

Then this test fails:

```
class TestStudent(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()
        Student.objects.create(am=2222, first_name="Chris",
                        last_name="Perivolas",
                        date_enrolled=datetime.date(year=2010, day=15,
                                                    month=2))
        Student.objects.create(am=7362, first_name="Mary",
                        last_name="Karagewrgena",
                        date_enrolled=datetime.date(year=2010, day=15,
                                                    month=2))

    def test_update(self):
        """
        """
        r = self.c.post("/profapp/students/2222/update/",
                        dict(am=7363, first_name="Chris",
                             last_name="Perivolas",
                             date_enrolled="3/15/2010",
                             semester=2,
                             undergraduate=1))
        self.assertEquals(Student.objects.filter(am=2222).exists(), False)
```

In short update view doesn't delete the old entry when updating a primary key. What is the best way of solving this?

Comment: Why is the PK ever being allowed to change? This will cause data integrity issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Django documentation, PK should never change. PK is what ties your object to a specific row in the DB. When you change the PK, Django loses the connection to the original row in the DB and assumes that you want to create another row.

You should add another field to act as changeable id if you really need it.

Comment: Well since it is bad practice anyway i will just not make it editable. Thank you.